# Programmatically generating UIButtons and associate those with IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ibaction

How do I do if I want to programatically generate a set of buttons and then associate those with IBActions? It's easy if I add the buttons in Interface Builder, but that I cannot do for this case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The buttons have the method `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`.

The code to use this would look like this:

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init...];
[myButton addTarget:something action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This assumes that your IBAction is named `myAction` and that `something` is the controller for which that action is defined.

Comment: When speciying a selector for a UIButton do you have to name a method with a single argument, the selected buttons id?  What would happen if I specified a method with no args?

Comment: @mattmccomb: From the documentation: "The action message may optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that order." You can have a method with zero, one or two arguments as the action. But don't forget to add the : at the end of the action name for each argument.

Answer (score 6):

First, create the button:

```
UIButton * btn;

btn = [ [ UIButton alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 200, 50 ) ];
```

Then adds an action:

```
[ btn addTarget: self action: @selector( myMethod ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown ];
```

Then adds the button to a view:

```
[ someView addSubView: btn ];
[ btn release ];
```

[UIControl reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[UIButton reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)