# Create IBOutlets and IBActions programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibaction, iboutlet

I want to create `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s in code rather than with the interface builder.

Let's say I've got a button on my UI called `btnDisplay`, and a method in my code called `displayMessage`. What would be the code I'd have to write to make it so that when `btnDisplay` is tapped, `displayMessage` runs?

Comment: [Here][1] is a nice explanation of how to make outlets programatically.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544279/can-you-hard-code-ibactions-and-iboutlets-in-xcode-rather-then-drag-them-manuall

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370031/programatically-generating-uibuttons-and-associate-those-with-ibaction Specifically, the `addTarget...` part.

Answer (score 10):

The way to do that with no outlets would be to give the button a tag in IB, say 128.  Then:

```
UIButton *btnDisplay = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:128];
[btnDisplay  addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedBtnDisplay:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then implement:

```
- (void) pressedBtnDisplay:(id)sender {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** using `IBOutlet` then you can add button using code.

```
UIButton *btnDisplay = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[btnDisplay setTitle:@"display" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnDisplay addTarget:self action:@selector(DisplayMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnDisplay];
```

If you use `IBOutlet` then you have to add below code in `viewDidLoad` or any other as per your requirement

```
[btnDisplay addTarget:self action:@selector(DisplayMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and implement this method.

```
-(void)DisplayMessage:(id)sender
{
    //do what you want
}
```

Maybe this will help you.